# Using an awk and sed command inside perl

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a simple awk and sed command that I want to write into a perl script or alternatively use the perl equivalent? Any pointers would be appreciated

```
sed -e '1d;4d' -e 's/#/Time/' -e 's/TGID/PID/' -e 's/%guest/%CPU/' -e 's/RSS/%MEM/'

awk '{ print $1,$3,$7,$13,$NF }'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without context, it's hard to give you exact answers, but Perl also has the `s///` command, so that should be easy.

To skip given lines, you can add something like

```
next if $. == 1 || $. == 4;
```

To print only the given columns, you usually keep them in an array, and then just

```
print "@F[0,2,6,12] ", scalar @F;
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks for the pointer! Much appreciated.